# Adding named controls to UserControls

Tags: .net, wpf, templates

I have a WPF User Control that really contains only a template expander. And when I use this control in my application I can't add a named control inside this expander.

What's the problem?

Comment: Can you provide some minimal sample code and the message of the error what you've got?

Comment: I can't provide the whole code. There is just UserControl in another CS/XAML files, there is just <expander/> and template. SO in MainWindows I just write <mycontrol:myexpander> <Label Name="rerr"/></mycontrol:myexpander>. I see the error

Comment: Error text: Cannot set Name attribute value 'rerr' on element 'Label'. 'Label' is under the scope of element 'myexpander', which already had a name registered when it was defined in another scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news: [read this at Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/483024/wpf-error-message-cannot-set-name-attribute-value-0-on-element-1-1-is-under-the-scope-of-element-2-which-already-had-a-name-registered-when-it-was-defined-in-another-scope) but also contains 2 workarounds. Read this and it might help you.

Comment: We'll have to see. I had this same problem I remembered after reading your question. You can become a registered member on the Connnect site and track the progress on the issue.